# Creating FIrestore Maps from the console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I've seen a post on how to create a Map in the Firebase console for the realtime database, but how do you create a Map (in order to create a mutable/queryable list structure) in Firebase from the console?  This is in order to create dummy data without doing so from the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firestore documents are essentially JSON, and JSON doesn't have a native map data type. The most direct mapping is to create a JSON object:

[image: Adding a field of type <code>object</code>]

Now you can add the keys and values under the new field.

Answer (score 1):

You can now create a map type in Firebase:

[image: firebase map]

Comment: this is more appropriate for firestore, I have not seen a object type in firestore data types